# How is it possible to cook up data attributes for an object on the fly?

Tags: python

[Dive into Python: HTTP Web Services](http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/etags.html) -

```
class DefaultErrorHandler(urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler):
    def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPError(
            req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
        result.status = code
        return result
```

`HTTPError` object initially has no attribute 'status', ie. status data attribute does NOT exist in `HTTPError` class definition. This means when I allocate memory for an instance of `HTTPError`, no allocation is made for status data attribute.

Then how can I on the fly create a status data attribute for the same instance in the next line? It seems something fascinating is going on beneath that I am unaware of which is giving python this flexibility which was never available in `C++/Java`

---

It's a pity I didn't catch this until Chapter 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a different notion of data types than C or Java.  Python does not allocate memory for the data members of an instance if it is created.  Instead, when an instance is created, it gets an `__dict__` attribute pointing to a dictionary mapping attribute names to values.  This dictionary is as dynamic as any standard Python dictionary.  If you do

```
result.status = code
```

an entry with the key `"status"` and the value `code` is added to this dictionary.

Comment: you also mentioned "instance". Since everything is an object, would it be safe to assume `__dict__` attribute exists for everything per se?

Comment: @Vaibhav: No, `__dict__` only exists for instances of user-defined classes.  That's why `i = 42; i.status = code` would fail.  Furthermore, you can prevent the creation of an instance dictionary using `__slots__` (just google for it for more information).